# Web development on Android tablet - no dev tools?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose you wanted to do web development on an Android tablet. There are some options available for code editors etc. One thing I can't get around is that Chrome for Android doesn't have dev tools. It doesn't even allow to disable the cache. Are there any other browsers that have the basic console and inspect element functionalities?

Please note that it doesn't have anything to do with remote debugging. I'm looking for a way to develop with an Android tablet only.

The only thing that comes to mind is BrowserStack, but it would be slow as hell especially on a mobile device.

Comment: Have you checked out [AIDE Web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.web) You should also specify what part of web development client or server (like nodejs)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do both, but it's the frontend that is a limitation. Because of lack of the dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

Look at these features requests for both Firefox and Chrome. Sadly, nobody seems to really care, given that remote debugging solves the problem when you have a computer next to your tablet.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=817837&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434065

In the meantime, you can :

- use a service like Browserstack with the devices (ex. Galaxy S9) that offer native debugging (the devtools are on your side, communicating with the remote mobile device)
- use that modified version of chromium and the accompanying hack : https://github.com/laem/chromium. Building a stable and fast version of Chrome is time and resource consuming, any help appreciated !

The best solution would obviously be to build Chromium with the devtools integrated, but I don't have enough knowledge : is it just an "if (!android) import DevTools" line to remove ? Or would it need lots of adaptations to work ? It's all HTML and JS as far as I know, so it shouldn't be that hard to get the console, debugger and inspector to work.